# compare two big strings with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two big strings A and B which store a HTML page. I want to compare those variables to see if pages are exactly same, Like `if(A === B) alert("same"); else alert ("different");`
but it fail to do such comparation , I suppose it is that because of very long string. How to compare in javascript such long strings ?

Comment: please paste your code.

Comment: And are there any errors in your JavaScript console (F12)? Have you escaped the string of HTML to avoid closing the string early (for example `'` cannot be contained within a string delimited by `'`, nor can a string delimited by `"` contain `"` characters.

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad; it doesn't make much (if any) sense at all and we'll need specific examples and errors to be able to help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: How long are these strings exactly? How do you build / fetch them?

Comment: You can try to use MD5 hashes of long strings

Comment: If you can allocate the strings, you can compare them. I tested to compare two strings of 128 MB each: http://jsfiddle.net/RfMBr/

Comment: to many vote downs, hate it !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [MD5 hashes of long strings](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html).

> MD5 (Message-Digest algorithm 5) is a widely-used cryptographic hash
>   function with a 128-bit hash value. MD5 has been employed in a wide
>   variety of security applications, and is also commonly used to check
>   the integrity of data. The generated hash is also non-reversable. Data
>   cannot be retrieved from the message digest, the digest uniquely
>   identifies the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
var a = 'abasdfasfasd23141234123412';
var b = 'abasdfasfasd23141234XXXXXX';
function compare(a,b) {
   var a_arr = a.split();
   var b_arr = b.split();
   if(a_arr.length != b_arr.length) {
      return false;
   } else {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a_arr.length ; i++) {
         if(a_arr[i] != b_arr[i]) return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```